# How to edit multiple row at one time on tree view Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I want to edit multiple rows at one time on treeview, and then save. But not edit each line andsave it immediately

Comment: if i may ask what is the reason for that?

Comment: Can you help me? I don't have for reason, but I want design that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't edit multiple row at one time on tree view. You can edit only one row at a time

Comment: You may explain why can't I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is not feasible to update all lines with time but you may try with following way which required more human efforts.

1. Select any records from list view.
2. Center you may see *"Action"* Button
3. Click on *"Action"* Button and choose *"Export"*
4. It will open one pop-up window
5. Add field as per your requirements
6. In pop-up window, you may find "Export To File" in footer
7. It will download excel file.
8. Update Excel file as per your necessary
9. Now go back to List view. You may find "Import" button
10. Browse file, check weather fields are mapping appropriate or not
11. Validate it

In that way, you may update all lines in one time.